# call to a member function describetable() on a non-object

Tags: php, zend-framework

I was trying one trick with the zendframework , I wanted to created a class that generate the dbTable automaticaly :

here is the class i defined :

```
class DbTable extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

public $db_table; 

public function __construct ($model_name='')
    {
        //echo "setting database";
        $this->db_table = $this->get_db_table($model_name);
    }


public function get_db_table($model_name='')
{
    if(!empty($model_name))
        {
        $model = 'Application_Model_DbTable_'.ucfirst($model_name);
        if (null === $this->db_table) 
            {
            $this->set_db_table($model);
            }
        return $this->db_table; 
        }
    else 
        {
            throw new Exception('Database Table was not defined');
        }

}

public function set_db_table($dbTable)
{
    if (is_string($dbTable)) {
        $dbTable = new $dbTable();
    }
    if (!$dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid table data gateway provided');
    }
   return $this->db_table = $dbTable;

}
```

}

and when I try to use it on the for example the User model to find a user with it's id with the function i defined:

```
public function find_by_id($id=0)
{
    $DbTable = new DbTable('User');
    $result = $database->find($id);
    if(empty($result))
        {
            return false;
        }

    else 
        {
    $row = $result->current();
    $entry = $this->instantiate($row);

    return $entry;  
        }


}
```

i get the error mentioned above !

Any help ? thanks anyway !

Comment: Are you sure that this error is connected with your class? You just create new  instance and in contructor set it's variable `$DbTable` (btw you should use `set_db_table` not `get_db_table` in contructor). I can't see connection with your class, unless you give more details (like where is `describetable()` used)

Comment: I think yes , the method _ get_db_table _ checks first if the '$db_table' is set , if no , then it would set it by calling the method _ set_db_table _ , I am sure that the describetable is run in the find method of the class **Zend_Db_Table_Abstrac** , so basically in this 'line  $result = $database->find($id);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss adapter. 
Try this: 
Replace

```
$DbTable = new DbTable('User');
$result = $database->find($id);
```

by

```
$DbTable = new DbTable('User');
$result = $DbTable->db_table->find($id);
```

Comment: Replace `$dbTable = new $dbTable();` by the 2 lines. Just for test, after, if it's correct, adapt this code. :)

Comment: Have you something with var_dump($dbadapter)?

Comment: protected '_pdoType' => string 'mysql' (length=5)
protected '_numericDataTypes' => 
    array (size=16)
      0 => int 0
      1 => int 1
      2 => int 2
      'INT' => int 0
      'INTEGER' => int 0
      'MEDIUMINT' => int 0
      'SMALLINT' => int 0
      'TINYINT' => int 0
      'BIGINT' => int 1
      'SERIAL' => int 1
      'DEC' => int 2
      'DECIMAL' => int 2
      'DOUBLE' => int 2
      'DOUBLE PRECISION' => int 2
      'FIXED' => int 2
      'FLOAT' => int 2
  protected '_defaultStmtClass' => string 'Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo' (length=21)

Comment: I change the answer. 
sorry, I have to go, keep me informed

Comment: new error message : unexpected '->' , i even tried new $dbTable->getAdapter(); and it says : Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: I had an another idea. I Change the answer . :)

Comment: it worked , but have no idea what was the problem , could you please give me a  hint ? and thank you so much

Comment: With your constructor, you assigne $db_table but in your function, you don't call this variable. :) Please, valid, this answer.

Comment: Thank's. :) Do you understand my comment about the answer?

Comment: Yes I did , so I should add (->db_table) to $DbTable inorder to use the whole functionalities !!??

Comment: Yes or better, transform $db_table in protect or private variable et add a getDbTable() method wich return this variable. Good luck. :)